# Solving system of equations iteratively

Tags: matrices, vectors, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of equations:

$$
\boldsymbol{X}_{n+1} = \boldsymbol{X}_{0} + \boldsymbol{X}_{n}
$$

Where $\boldsymbol{X}_{0}$ is my initial calculation and each of the $\boldsymbol{X}$ is a vector.

What methods are there to solve this iteratively?

Comment: Isn't it as simple as $\mathbf X_{n}=(n+1)\cdot\mathbf{X}_0$? I mean every $\mathbf{X}_n$ is different to the previous one by a single term of $\mathbf{X}_0$ added to it.

Comment: Often, it is good to write out first few terms of the recursively defined sequence and spot the pattern, IF you can't see it quickly.

More practice and these things become obvious to you.